# Diener vs. Knecht

Tags: meaning, difference, noun

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Begriffen *Diener* und *Knecht*?

Hat sich die Bedeutung dieser beiden Wörter in der Vergangenheit (letzte 200 Jahre) verändert?

**Ergänzung**

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Knecht) erklärt zu *Knecht* (u.a.):

> 1. (veraltend) männliche Person, die für einen Bauern arbeitet, auf einem Bauernhof angestellt ist

Ist dies die einzige Bedeutung, die das Wort früher hatte? Oder wurde es damals auch in dem Sinn verwendet, wie wir heute *Diener* benutzen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question can easily be answered by consulting a dictionary

Comment: engl. Wikipedia erklärt Knecht als servant (=Diener), was nicht ausreicht. Somit kann es hier durchaus mal erklärt werden.

Comment: @Burki: Wörterbücher sagen mir aber nichts über die Bedeutung der Begriffe vor 200 Jahren. Zumindest kenne/habe ich keins, dass mir das darlegt.

Comment: Schau mal auf [Duden Online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sklave). Aus meiner Sicht beantwortet das Deine Frage. Anderenfalls solltest Du evtl. darlegen, warum es das nicht tut.

Comment: To get the question re-opened please make an [edit] (e.g. put in a dictionary reference). This will push your question into the reopen review queue visible to other community members.

Comment: @jor Jetzt wird das zu einer Frage … die allerdings nach anderen Tags ruft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ein Diener ist meist eine Person, die sich um das häusliche Wohlergehen des Herrn bemüht.

Ein Knecht ist eine landwirtschaftliche Hilfskraft.

---

Aufgrund Takkat's Kommentar hier eine genauere Definition nach dwds.de:

> **Knecht** m. ehemals 'in einem Arbeitsverhältnis bei einem Bauern stehender Landarbeiter', auch 'Diener, Untergebener, Unfreier, Unterdrückter', ahd. (8. Jh.), mhd. asächs. *kneht* 'Knabe, Jüngling, Bursche, junger Mann in lernender und dienender Stellung, Diener, Knappe, Krieger, Held, Lehrling, Geselle'

Daher ist *Knecht Rupprecht* in der Bedeutung *Knappe* zu sehen.

Dagegegen

> **Diener** m. 'Aufwärter, Hausangestellter', auch 'wer im Auftrage einer Institution, in der Bindung an eine Aufgabe seine Pflicht erfüllt'

Man mag hier meinen, dass Knecht und Diener als Begriff austauschbar seien. Ich persönlich (und auch weitere Personen, die ich dazu gefragt habe) kennen *Knecht* jedoch ausschließlich in der Bedeutung als "Landarbeiter", der harte Arbeiten zu verrichten hat (keinesfalls würde ich einem Knecht beispielsweise die Aufgabe des Ordnens der Kleidung oder des Einlassens eines Bades zuordnen), ebenso wie ich nie den Begriff *Diener* für jemanden verwenden würde, der mit der Sense auf dem Feld Korn schneidet.